# How to access the NSView from a NSViewController contained in another NSViewController

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsview

So here's my pending architecture right now--

I have a xib that contains 2 views; and in that xib I also put in 2 objects, view controllers.
Each view controller has their `view` connected to one view in the xib.

The file's owner of this xib is a master view controller, that has two view controller properties bound to the view controllers in the xib

Now I have a `NSWindowController`, that creates an instance of the master view controller.

When I try to add `masterViewController.subViewController1.view` to my window, I find that `subViewController1` is `nil`

When I am initializing masterViewController in my NSWindowController, I'm calling:

```
[masterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:"SubViews"]
```

and it initializes it properly, all the code is set, but my `subViewControllers` are never initialized.

I thought that if I called `initWithNibName`, it would load the `subViewControllers` in my xib and connect them to the properties I had declared in my `masterViewController`.  But that doesn't appear to be working, because the `subViewControllers` are `nil` after the `initwithNibName` call.

I was thinking of explicitly calling `[[subViewController alloc] init]` in the `masterViewController`, but that doesn't seem to be working either.

If I have to, I will split my xib into 2 xibs with 2 separate views and the viewcontrollers as their owners-- but in my mind it seems like theoretically I should be able to create 2 view controllers in one xib.

If I'm doing something stupid, please let me know too.  I'm mostly just experimenting and trying to find the best way of implementing this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you need viewcontrollers in the first place?  Are you trying to develop an iOS application with Cocoa APIs?  It's usually WindowControllers that you use.  I don't use the window controller, often, any more.

Comment: @ElTomato ah sorry this is an OSX application.  I probably am architecting this wrong.  What do you use instead of NSWindowController?  I have a NSWindow, that contains a button that displays a popover with more info.  But both the button and the popover contain text based on which user is logged in.  So I created a root viewcontroller that contains both the button and the popover, and that viewcontroller sits on the main window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the sub view controllers were never loaded, only initialized.  I had to access the view in the base view controller to load the view controllers, and then their views.